# A world based on a simulation by dying humans

Tags: society, technology, politics

This question is based on the following premises:

1. We have the technology capable of running a Full Dive Simulation wherein the simulation runs at a rate faster than real time. (1 second in real time is 3 seconds in the simulation)
2. Aging in the simulation is non-existent. (You will be on your prime upon entry)
3. Two-way communication is possible.
4. The simulation will *start* as an open society. No governments, groups, law, etc.
5. Technology and physics in the simulation will be similar to the existing world. (updates possible)

Will we be able to improve the real world, if the ones living in the simulation is practically given a "second chance" in life; in the aspects of human development, politics, art, etc? Is it possible that we will learn anything from the simulation?

Comment: You seem to have the simulation running *faster* than real time: 1 second of real time allows 3 seconds of simulator time to pass.

Comment: Are people interacting with the simulation as avatars? If so, won't their awareness of the nature of the simulation change the results? Won't they just import their own laws and politics from the real world? Can they leave the simulation? If not, what stops their real world bodies from atrophying?

Comment: What happens if you kill someone in the simulation? Does anything in the simulation have meaningful value in the real world? Could I develop software there and export it?

Comment: "learn anything" is quite broad. A lot depends on ethics, for example. And on the "how you are you" in the simulation. **Can people in it act as they would? Or only as the software designer already predicted?** This is the main thing you need to clarify. Narrowing what would you like to learn would help as well.

Comment: @JohnDallman: Simulation is running faster than real-time. -- exactly

Comment: @SteveBird Are people interacting with the simulation as avatars? -- Somehow i guess? Something like the matrix. Won't they just import their own laws and politics from the real world? --The simulation is supposed to be built from scratch to see how people would react to a world with no laws etc. To leave, they just have to communicate with the real world which is possible. If they die in the real world, they'd just be disconnected. Again, somehow similar to the matrix.

Comment: @Mołot Can people in it act as they would? Or only as the software designer already predicted? --They would act as they would. What i mean with learn anything is: for example, in the simulation, the people in it may find a way to live "as one" with no country/politics since it is non-existent on creation. Or maybe create a new one. A possibility of recreating the political conditions in the real world is possible, but the changes of them creating a new system that may be relevant to the real world isn't impossible either.

Comment: @Separatrix You cannot kill anyone in the simulation (This should be in the premises stated above. [how convenient]) because killing someone in the simulation defeats the purpose of providing dying people of having to live a "second chance".      Does anything in the simulation have meaningful value in the real world? --The inhabitants may/may not create something. That is what this question is trying to answer. I'm just gathering different perspectives.  --all actions in the simulation is supposedly being recorded since it is included in the purpose of its existence to monitor its inhabitants

Comment: Since you are using real people to interact with the simulation, what's the advantage of having the simulation run faster than real time? Presumably all interactions between people in the simulation will be at real world speeds (unless you can get people to think faster in the simulation). Also if the person sleeps for 8 hours in the real world, they would be sleeping for the equivalent of a full day in the simulation.

Comment: @A.Arc: Corrected the question to explain simulation is running faster.

Comment: @A.Arc, you say physics works, but you can't kill people. What is the outcome of hitting another avatar repeatedly with a large axe?

Comment: What do you mean Dying Humans? What is the scenario because it makes a lot of difference. If you mean someone just dying then we can extend their life. If you mean our planet is messed up, possibly, but not in the way you're describing the simulated world. If you mean the universe is dying... maybe, but highly debatable.

Comment: Yes, you even do not need full simulation, u can learn from mmorpg as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 second in real time is 3 seconds in the simulation

...

> Will we be able to improve the real world, if the ones living in the simulation is practically given a "second chance" in life; in the aspects of human development, politics, art, etc? Is it possible that we will learn anything from the simulation?

Short answer: yes.

Since your simulation is 3x faster than real time, of course it can lead to improvements in the real world. From your comments I gather that people in the simulation cannot *directly* affect the real world, but that's fine. You have indicated that two-way communication is possible and relatively easy.

The simplest and most profound way the simulation can help the real world is in the acquisition of knowledge.

The simulated humans can make advances in almost all fields, including mathematics, science, language, art, music, social sciences, and pass on what they've learned via the communication with the real world for implementation and application there.

Since everyone's "in their prime", health research would be somewhat limited, but *some* health fields like anatomy could still be studied. Since simulated humans simply "wake up" in the real world if they're killed, and you have an open society with no government (and hence, no medical regulatory bodies), [vivisections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivisection) are back on the menu!

One potential hitch is that I have a little trouble believing in the fidelity of the physics simulation, since it's difficult to 100% simulate something that we don't fully understand yet. However, even that need not be a huge barrier. Simulated humans can just tell the real humans which experiments to run, in cases where the simulation is giving unexpected results. Then, the simulated/real humans can work together to update the simulation with their improved understanding of physics.

Going much beyond this would put the answer into idea generation territory, so I won't go there, but I still believe *knowledge* is the right answer, and everything else is just a spin-off.

Comment: "some health fields like anatomy could still be studied." - how? If it's a simulation, anatomy is limited to what is already known to simulation engine, isn't it? Also, physics experiments. You got it all wrong. Only experiments worth anything are those in which we don't know the results yet. And if results are expected, it means we learned nothing new because it was already known if it was already implemented, right?

Comment: @Mołot Of course there are obvious problems with simulations based on current knowledge in general. I attempted to address the spirit of this with the physics discussion: the simulated humans aren't *doing* the experiments, they're banging away at the theoretical physics and coming up with practical experiments their real-world counterparts can run, *then* they update the sim. The anatomy thing was mainly for humour, but even limited simulations can exhibit emergent effects, so without medical regulation, some experiments we won't do in the real world might still teach us something in sim.

Comment: I was a student of physics. And have friends with doctorates in it. The problem now is that, in particle physics, building equipment for experiments is much slower than "banging away at the theoretical physics". So bottleneck will stay a bottleneck and this would only speed up things that are quite fast anyway. For anatomy? Well, maybe... if simulation was at physical / chemical level, then yes, you're right.

Comment: So was I. :-) Remember, the key (I think) to this question is that the sim is 3x real time, and they have two-way communication. That means the simulation doesn't have to be perfect (it won't be). There are reams of papers being published in theoretical journals today that continue to accelerate experimental physics, math, and even philosophy; this question isn't *only* about physics. Anyway, I really appreciate the feedback. If my answer can be improved, I'm open to suggestions! If you simply disagree and still feel I "got it all wrong", that's fine too; I'd enjoy seeing another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have many questions.

**First, in the simulation, how real is death?** One of the reasons people are so terrible in MMOs is because it isn't real. You can hurt and "kill" another player and their real-life counterpart will be sitting at home, waiting for a re-spawn. When faced with a consequence-free environment, humans tend to be more awful than they generally are. This is not about government, this is about the fundamentals of how the program works.

**Who is in the simulation?** If your answer is "ordinary people" or "everyone" then you will certainly be in for a disappointment as far as progress is concerned.

**What do you mean by 2 way communication?** are you talking chat bubble? How about talking? Does this mean that you can only have a discussion with one person at a time? Does it mean if three people want to chat, they can't? Does it mean that a lecture is impossible because that's one person talking to a crowd? If you mean that it matches the real world, do say so. If there's a big difference, please delineate that difference. How we communicate is fundamentally important to advancement.

**The simulation will start as an open society. No governments, groups, law, etc. Does this mean everyone has clothes? Or houses?** The capability to form groups has to be present in the initial program, even if there aren't any groups present to start with. Basically, do they arrive naked? If it's totally open, that means that no one will have anything to begin with, and without governments, or law or a beginning society, there won't even be buildings. You have to have some sort of base structure in place. Even IF everyone is assigned a dwelling, that's still a structure. No game world that I know of is COMPLETELY open. There's generally a pathway set up, even in a supposedly "open" world.

**Are the parameters of the created reality exactly like those in the real world?** As type_outcast pointed out, in order for science to advance through a simulated world, you'd ALREADY have to know all the rules of reality in order to program a simulated world which matches it completely and whose results would be valid in the real world. The only way to get around it is if your humans don't actually understand how their own tech works, or it's like a gift from aliens or something.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly no. Do we learn anything today watching The Sims video game? Yes, we can see variations we haven't thought of, but we get no new phenomena that wasn't programmed in. Now, your sim proposal has actual intelligences in it. Does that change the answer? Well...

Your sim is running faster than real time. That means -- pretty much by definition -- that some part of the simulation is being modeled based on an over simplification used to make it computable. Probably environment stuff like the weather is more table driven than actually computed. You're clearly not simulating biology at its core, which means you're taking shortcuts on chemistry... even without the no-aging thing, you probably aren't simulating individual atomic (or smaller) interactions.

Basically, faithful simulation of a phenomenon always runs slower than the reality. That's a pretty basic proof in computability math -- the state vector of any object going through computation is slower than the parallel update of that phenomenon. Now, sometimes we can find simplifications that don't mess significantly with the final outcome, but that's unlikely to be the case in a whole world sim.

All of these shortcuts mean that you might not get useful info from the sim. No aging will skew psychology significantly. Simplified weather means scientists inside the sim will only discover the meterologucal principles used to program the sim, but nothing new. The same applies to every other simulated science. Even if you did simulate with everything we know right now, your in-sim scientists would never make new science.

What they MIGHT do is create new technologies from existing science. Given the tools we have now, they could build up a richer combination of those tools faster than reality.